# Find the general solution to $y'' + 4y' + 4y = x^{-2}e^{-2x}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution to $y'' + 4y' + 4y = x^{-2}e^{-2x}$

My attempt:

For $y''+4y'+4y=0$

The auxiliary equation is :

$m^2+4m+4=0$

$(m+2)^2=0$

$y_p = x^2(A_nx^n+A_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+A_1x+A_0)e^{-2x}$

where $(A_nx^n+A_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+A_1x+A_0)=1 $

$y_p = x^2e^{-2x}$

Therefore the general solution is:

y = $x^{2}e^{-2x}+c_{1}e^{-2x}+xc_{2}e^{-2x}$

My question is

(1)is my answer correct?

(2)how to determine $(A_nx^n+A_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+A_1x+A_0)$ for other case?

Comment: have you tried putting it into the ode? Also are you trying to solve $... = x^{-2}\mathrm{e}^{2x}$ or  $... = x^{2}\mathrm{e}^{-2x}$ as the ode suggests the first and your solution suggests the latter.

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo mistake, corrected

Comment: yes, i put into the ode to solve by Method of Undetermined Coefficients

Comment: you still have a typo in the first two types you write the ode.

Comment: I think it is all right now

Comment: @E.H.E hear hear. OP from your solution you can not get $x^{-2}\mathrm{e}^{-2x}$ which your ode suggests.

Comment: Because I find that If $α$ is a double root of $ax^{2}+bx+c$, then $s=2$ for $y_p = x^s(....)$      from this website :http://www.sosmath.com/tables/diffeq/diffeq.html

Comment: Since tou already found a common term $e^{-2x}$, why don't you try to set $y=z\,e^{-2x}$ and see what the ode becomes ?

Comment: @PakLong That technique helps when you have a non negative integer power times an exponential. You have a negative integer power, however. This is bad because differentiating a negative power makes the power go further away from zero, which breaks the method.

Comment: @lan What method should be used?

Comment: I think I should try Variation of Parameters

Comment: I tried my best to get this $ y = c_{1}e^{-2x} + xc_{2}e^{-2x} - (lnx +1 )e^{-2x}$ , using Variation of Parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{array}{l}
 y'' + 4y' + 4y = {x^{ - 2}}{e^{ - 2x}} \\ 
  \Rightarrow {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} \left( {{D^2} + 4D + 4} \right)y = {x^{ - 2}}{e^{ - 2x}} \\ 
 {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {D^2} + 4D + 4 = 0{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt}  \Rightarrow {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\left( {D + 2} \right)^2} = 0{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt}  \Rightarrow {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} D =  - 2{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} ,{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt}  - 2 \\ 
 {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {y_h} = {c_1}{e^{ - 2x}} + {c_2}x{e^{ - 2x}} \\ 
 {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {y_p} = \frac{1}{{{D^2} + 4D + 4}}\left( {{x^{ - 2}}{e^{ - 2x}}} \right) = \frac{1}{{{{\left( {D + 2} \right)}^2}}}\left( {{x^{ - 2}}{e^{ - 2x}}} \right) \\ 
 {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt}  = {e^{ - 2x}}\frac{1}{{{D^2}}}\left( {{x^{ - 2}}} \right) = {e^{ - 2x}}\int {\int {{x^{ - 2}}dx} dx}  \\ 
 {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt}  = {e^{ - 2x}}\int {\left( { - {x^{ - 1}} + {c_1}} \right)} dx = {e^{ - 2x}}\left( { - \ln \left| x \right| + {c_1}x + {c_2}} \right) \\ 
 {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} y = {c_1}{e^{ - 2x}} + {c_2}x{e^{ - 2x}} - {e^{ - 2x}}\ln \left| x \right| \\ 
 \end{array}\