# Find the general solution to $y′′+4y′+4y=x^{−2}e^{-2x}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Previous post : [Find the general solution to $y'' + 4y' + 4y = x^{-2}e^{-2x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1554642/find-the-general-solution-to-y-4y-4y-x-2e-2x/1554748#1554748)

Instead of the method I used in previous post which led a wrong answer, I use Method of Variation of Parameters to solve, here is my attempt:

$y′′+4y′+4y=x^{−2}e^{-2x}$

$y_{c}(x)=c_{1}e^{-2x}+c_{2}xe^{-2x}$

$y_{1}(x)=e^{-2x}$ and $y_{2}(x)=xe^{-2x}$

$W= \begin{vmatrix}
        e^{-2x} & xe^{-2x} \\
        -2e^{-2x} & e^{-2x}-2xe^{-2x} \\
        \end{vmatrix}=e^{-4x}$

$$y_{p}(x
)=-e^{-2x}\int {xe^{-2x}\over e^{-4x}x^{2}e^{2x}}dx +xe^{-2x}\int {e^{-2x}\over e^{-4x}x^{2}e^{2x}}dx = -e^{-2x}\ln\left\lvert x \right\rvert -e^{-2x}$$

Therefore, $y(x)=c_{1}e^{-2x}+c_{2}xe^{-2x}-e^{-2x}\ln\left\lvert x \right\rvert -e^{-2x}$

---

I know the correct answer is $y(x)=c_{1}e^{-2x}+c_{2}xe^{-2x}-e^{-2x}\ln\left\lvert x \right\rvert $

I don't know why my answer has extra this :  $ -e^{-2x}$

Comment: Doubt; am I right in guessing $y_{p}(x)=-y_1\int {y_2\over Wx^{2}e^{2x}}dx +y_2\int {y_1\over Wx^{2}e^{2x}}dx$? What is the $x^{2}e^{2x}$ term in denominator? Why -ve for first term? (To learn; will be great if you can help!)

Comment: It comes from the left had side of the question,$ g(x) = x^{-2}e^{-2x}$

Comment: Thank you! And what about the alternating signs?

Comment: I don't know the proof, but you can refer to this :http://www.sosmath.com/tables/diffeq/diffeq.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y(x)=c_{1}e^{-2x}+c_{2}xe^{-2x}-e^{-2x}\ln\left\lvert x \right\rvert -e^{-2x}$$
$$y(x)=(c_{1}-1)e^{-2x}+c_{2}xe^{-2x}-e^{-2x}\ln\left\lvert x \right\rvert $$
$$y(x)=k_1e^{-2x}+c_{2}xe^{-2x}-e^{-2x}\ln\left\lvert x \right\rvert $$
so your answer is correct

Comment: OHHH, Thank you ! I forget the fact that c$_{1}$ is any arbitrary const